# Mixed Binomial and Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, variance

> **Problem** Consider the mixed binomial distribution $Bin(n, U)$, where U has a standard uniform(0,1) distribution.
>
> (i) Compute E[X | U]
>
> (ii) Compute Var [X | U]
>
> (iii) Find the mean and variance of X

Following is my thought process, I'm not sure if they are even remotely close to be on the right track.

(i) E[X|U] = E[$\frac{f(X,U)}{f_U(u)}$] = $\frac{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x\space{n \choose x}  \; p^x (1-p)^{n-x} U(0,1)}{E[U(0,1)]}$ = $\frac{np}{\frac{1}{2}}$ ,  since p is uniform distribution probability will converge to 1 and np = n. Therefore E[X|U] = 2n?

I assume that p= probability of standard Uniform distribution, which is 1?

(ii) Var [X | U]=E[$X^2 | U] - (E[X | U])^2$ = $np(1-p) - (2n)^2$

(iii) $$E[X] = E(E[X|U]) = E[np] = np  \quad  (since \space X|U \sim Binomial(n,U))  $$

$$Var[X]=Var(E[X|U]) + E(Var[X|U]) $$
$$Since \space Var(E[X|U])=Var(nP) = n^2U(0,1)= n^2(1)$$
$$E(Var[X|U]) = nE[p(1-p)] = 0?$$
$$Therefore \space Var[X]=n^2?$$

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not remotely close.   There is no $p$ involved anywhere.

You have been told that $X\mid U\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n, U)$ and $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0;1)$.

(i) $\mathsf E(X\mid U)$ will be a function of $U$, and further ...

> ... it is clearly going to be the mean of the binomial distribution, $\mathcal {Bin}(n, U)$. $$\mathsf E(X\mid U) = nU$$

(ii) Similarly for $\mathsf{Var}(X\mid U)$

(iii) This relies on the tower properties.$$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid U))\\ \mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(X\mid U))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid U))$$

Well, you should be able to complete that now.

Comment: Can I assume U=1, and E[U] = 1/2? If so
$$\mathbb{E}[X|U]=nU = n?\\
\text{Var}[X|U]=nU(1-U) = 0 ?\\
\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid U)) = \mathsf E(nU)= n\mathsf E(U) = \frac{n}{2}?\\ \mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(X\mid U))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid U)) = 0 + n^2? $$  Sorry I just learned the method and is still confused. Still struggling with the learning curve.

Comment: No; not the first two.  $~\Bbb E[X\mid U]~=~nU~$ is what it is; a random variable determined by $U$. There is no need to assume $U$ is any value. That is the answer.  Then indeed, using the tower property and substituting this result gives: $$\begin{align}\Bbb E(X)~&=~\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid U))\\[1ex] &=~\Bbb E(nU) \\[1ex] &=~ n/2\end{align}$$.  Likewise $\Bbb{Var}[X\mid U]~=~nU(1-U)$ so: $$\begin{align}\Bbb{Var}(X)~&=~\Bbb E(\Bbb {Var}(X\mid U))+\Bbb{Var}(\Bbb E(X\mid U))\\[1ex] &=~\Bbb E(nU-nU^2)+\Bbb{Var}(nU)\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$